# Yii CGridView - Drag and Select Rows

Tags: php, yii

Does CGridView support a drag and select functionality for rows? Like, click one row, drag and select all rows you rollover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. You have to look at jquery draggable and selectable plugins for that

Answer (score 2):

The following yii-wiki provides an excellent step-by-step guide for how to use jQuery's "sortable" to make the CGridview's rows sortable:
[creating-a-jqueryui-sortable-cgridview](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/238/creating-a-jqueryui-sortable-cgridview/)